# SSRS pass parameter to subreport in same page by click the ID field

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I am using SQL Server 2016 SSRS. I have a report page with main table shows student names and at the page bottom have a subreport shows student exam scores by pass in the `studID`parameter.

I have tried "Go to report" action on ID field. It opened the subreport instead of showing the subreport at page end. User have to click "back" in order to go back to main report.

I want to setup that, when the user click the main table ID, the subreport should show the student's exam scores. How could I set the expected result?

Comment: You can create a drill down report to show or hide a sub report details when click.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this exactly how you want to but you can simulate it.

Setup your main report so that it has a hidden parameter `StudID`. Set it to be NULL as default.

Insert your subreport into the main report and set it's parameter to the hidden `StudID` parameter. Set the subreport's visibilty hidden is the `StudID` = Nothing so it won;t display when you first run the report.

Now, on the student names in the main report, change the action so that instead of opening your subreport, it opens the main report. Pass in all the parameters from the main report, plus the student ID from the main reports dataset (just as you are currently doing for the subreport).

It means an ugly screen refresh each time but it's as close as you can get using native reports.

If this does not make sense, let me know and I'll post a full answer.

Comment: When I click on student name, the subreport works as expected, but the main report will be reduced to show only the clicked student. I want the main report remain no change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't need to filter the main report at all. If you struggle, edit the question to show your report design including all existing parameters and show, if applicable,  where they are are used in your datasets

Comment: I have double checked no filter is setup in main report. If it is not an expected behaviour, maybe I should delete everything and re-create.

Comment: I guessing the student ID  parameter is restricting the data that is being bought back.. so the main report needs to bring back all the results regardless of the student ID passed to it.  Student ID parameter should only be referenced by the subreport and NOT the main report

Comment: I'll try to post a sample later today so you can see it working